# Intellij Cannot Resolve file/directory

Tags: java, intellij-idea, fxml

I have a JavaFX project that I've been working on for sometime now. However today, I started getting errors from my `.java` files`could not resolve` from all Java class files. Checked on the internet and it seemed that `File>Invalidate Cache/Restart` was the solution. It was not for me. I had to reinstall my `jdk` and reimport my project for it to work again. Now those errors are gone, but all my FXML files have error lines again. For example, I have an `ImageView` which says `Cannot resolve directory 'file'` like this:

```
 <ImageView disable="true" fitHeight="30.0" fitWidth="22.0" layoutX="7.0" layoutY="161.0" opacity="0.68" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                    <image>
                        <Image url="file:/home/user/IdeaProjects/myproject/resources/home.png" />
                    </image>
                </ImageView>
```

If I hover on `'home'` it says cannot resolve directory home, same thing for each folder there.

I tried going to `File>Project Structure>Modules` to set the directory there, but everything looked in order.

When I run the program however, the icons are visible in it. What could be the problem and how could I fix it?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to use absolute paths in your code. You should use the paths relative to the resource root.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I had originally done this, however the images dont appear when I run the application

Comment: Make sure the resources directory is configured as the resource root per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-content-roots.html.

Comment: go to Settings > Directories and select your asset root folder from the right-hand panel. Then mark it as Resource Root by clicking the button above the file browser.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, try delete the folder **.idea**  and reimport your project for it to work again